# How to log correlationID (or something like that) in amazon CloudWatch with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to search log in cloudWatch by an specific Id who correlate all logs in requisition. but i dont know how to log a correlation id with c#.

I'm logging this way:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Logging the value of foo", CORRELATIONID);
```

this correlationID will be unic by all logs in thread.

Comment: That’s a log scope. What kind of application are you writing?

Comment: its a Web API application with .net 6.0

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0